# How do I get a param inside an URL in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I use django admin and want to access the object id in an URL like this: `http://localhost:8000/polls/platform/837/change`

```
class PlatformAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def get_queryset(self, request):
    print(request.??)
```

So what should be returned is the `837`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelAdmin` class has `get_object` method which receives `object_id`, so basically you need to override that method.

```py
class PlatformAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_object(self, request, object_id, form_field=None):
        # print(object_id)
        return super().get_object(request, object_id, form_field=None)
```